# Automatically initiating the keyboard in Windows Tablet when tap on the text field

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, windows-8.1, tablet

I developed a desktop application using Winforms. When I installed the application on a **Windows 8.1 Tablet** the application works just fine but the only issue that I'm facing is that the keyboard doesn't automatically appear when I tap on a text fields. Instead, I have to tap or click the Touch keyboard icon on the right side of the taskbar to make it happen.

Is there some way to make it work? Because it's not good for user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

[How to make Windows 8 tablet open the on-screen-keyboard when an input field gets focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761421/how-to-make-windows-8-tablet-open-the-on-screen-keyboard-when-an-input-field-get?rq=1)

There are also quite a few other threads out there regarding this topic.

And from my own personal experience:

```
private void OpenOnScreenKeyboard()
{   
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
}

private void CloseOnScreenKeyboard()
{   
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("TabTip"))
    {
        process.Kill(); // Kill any previous processes running
    }
}
```

You will likely only need the last line from the above `OpenPenInput()` method.  I also edited the registry so the handwriting panel would be the displayed when the keyboard was opened.  But that part only works in Windows 8.1 and below.  I haven't tried getting it to work in Win10.  The last line of `OpenPenInput()` should be all that you need.

Comment: @psyLogic - I've included the code that I used to implement this feature into my WinForms app.

Comment: there's some redundant lines of code in your answer you might want to edit your answer. I've accepted the answer but please make the necessary changes.

Comment: @psyLogic - Is this answer no longer working for you? Just curious as to why you unaccepted as the answer.

Comment: I told you to edit the code but you haven't, your code opens the pen Input. My question was about opening the keyboard. Now that I have your attention please make the necessary changes as your answer can be misleading to other readers or allow me the courtesy of doing it. We are here to help :)

Comment: @psyLogic - If you see my edit history I did remove some of the redundant code when you accepted the answer.  I figured leaving the pen input code in there can't hurt anyone but regardless, I have removed it.

Comment: Sure it wouldn't hurt anyone(well it didn't hurt me) but some of the visitors here are naive, so we should make sure that our posts don't confuse anyone.That being said your post did help me and I really appreciate your effort and am thankful for that.+1 :)